# Can Anybody Please Explain The Below Statement

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
    function AvoidSpace(event) {
        var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
        if (k >= 42 && k <= 57 || k == 32 || k == 61 || k == 13) return false;
    }

    function ExceptNumber(event) {
        var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
        if (k >= 0 && k <= 47 || k >= 58 && k <= 122) return false;
    }

    function NumChar(event) {
        var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
        if (k >= 0 && k <= 31 || k >= 33 && k <= 64 || k >= 91 && k <= 96) return false;
    }

    function clearFunction() {
        document.getElementById('register').reset();
    }
</script>
```

My doubt is:
var k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;

I was confused with the above statement. One thing is for sure that the above statement is for event validation only..I'm not getting the explanation..Can anyone please help me in finding out what actually the above statement does?? Seeking for a brief explanation in `JAVASCRIPT` only

Comment: [event.which](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/which), [event.keyCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode)

Comment: Also, [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`k = event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode`

Means `if you passed event variable to function use it; Else - use global event`

It's ternary operator and can be expanded to

```
if (event == true) {
    k = event.which;
} else {
    k = window.event.keyCode;
}
```

It will return which key was pressed (integer value; key code)

Comment: Sir, One more Small Question..May I Know What "event.which" does here?

Comment: `event.which` returns the keycode that was pressed, as shown here https://jsfiddle.net/od8ogtqa/1/ @ManojKarthik

Comment: `if (event == true) {` is incorrect. It should be `if (event) {`. Yours will always be `false`.

Comment: @squint Why? It's not `===`, just `==` so `event` will be converted to boolean. Or am I missing something?

Comment: As a matter of general practice it is not a good idea to test for explicit equality with `true` unless that is exactly the condition you require. In this case you are testing whether `event` is defined, so the best test would seem to be `if (event == undefined)`. In any case, `if (event)` is not the same as `if (event == true)`, so care is necessary.

Comment: @Justinas: The `==` doesn't convert to a boolean. It follows a somewhat complex recursive algorithm of type coercion, usually converting both operands to numbers. You can verify this with a simple test `console.log({foo: "bar"} == true); // false`

Answer (score 1):

This syntax:

```
expression ? value1 : value2;
```

Is known as a ternary operator.  If the expression is true, it will return value1 otherwise return value2.  In this case an object (event) is used as the expression, so it will evaluate if it exists (not null) or not.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers use keyCode, others use which.
That instruction is only for cross browser issue, and is used to retrive the key code during keypress and keyup events

Answer (score 0):

```
event ? event.which : window.event.keyCode;
```

This is a ternary operator. If the thing before the question mark is true or "truthy," it returns the expression before the colon; if it is false or "falsey," it returns the expression after.

If `event` is defined (i.e., it was passed into the function) it will be "truthy," which means that it is true if evaluated as a boolean even though it isn't of a boolean type.

So what this does is check if `event` was passed into the function, and  set `k` either to `event.which` (the key code that caused the event) if it was passed in, or to the the keycode from the global `window` event as a fallback otherwise.